# Storing metadata file to Cassandra File System

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am storing metadata files in cassandra file system but not sure how it would impact read/write queries used to get data from cassandra tables.

Previously I was storing metadata files to S3 but because of consistency and latency issue started using cassandra file system(cfs) . But I am not sure what would be impact on cassandra queries used to get data from different keyspaces if files stored in CFS grows in future. My specific questions are:

1. If we start storing files in CFS then will it impact cassandra cluster if file size grows in future?
2. How cassandra maintains replication and consistency policies for files stored in CFS?

Comment: You are asking some good questions here but Stack Overflow works best if you ask just a single question. It may be hard to get somebody to answer all of your 5+ questions when presented in this format. Welcome to Stack Overflow and good luck finding your answers.

Comment: Hi Thanks for suggestion, I tried to edit but looks like I don't have edit rights